# getting an attribute-value in a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this question has been asked here on SO, i just don't know the right word.

I have this input tag:

```
 <input type = "text" class="inputbox holdout-7"></input>
```

How do I get the holdout's value of 7 from the class using javascript?

This is because I wanted to add custom attributes but when the page is rendered, my custom attribute is not displayed. Some advised me to put them in a class instead.

For example:

```
<input type = "text" class = "inputbox" holdout="7"></input>
```

when the page is rendered, the holdout is not included, therefore I cannot get the value.

Comment: It's not a value, holdout-7 is a class just like inputbox

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: i want to store a value to a custom attribute, like holdout = 7. but the page does not render the holdout attribute that I used. it only renders default attributes like size, class, label etc..

Comment: First, `<input>` elements do not have closing tags, secondly you should prepend `data-` to any custom attributes e.g. `data-holdout="7"`

Comment: @dsg how should I include it in the tag? will I still need to put it in the class?

Comment: `<input type="text" class="inputbox" data-holdout="7"> `

Comment: @BreaktheLaw if the `holdout` value is static, you can put in your element while cosntructing the page itself. If its dynamic then you can add the value using `setAttribute('data-holdout',value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var inputBox = document.querySelector(".inputbox"),
    classname = inputBox.className,
    regEx = /holdout-(\d+)/,
    holdoutValue = classname.match(regEx)[1];
```

It will return you `7`

To set that as attribute in your input box:

```
inputBox.setAttribute("data-holdout",holdoutValue);
```

it's recommended to use `data-holdout` instead of `holdout`.

Comment: Actually the holdout value is saved in the database and is configured when retrieving it. It is generated when I pass an XML parameter to my form. Where should i put the data-holdout? inside the class? sorry for noobish question.

Comment: You must put it in the element as attribute

Comment: Like `<input type="text" class="inputbox" data-holdout="7">` This will give you the flexibility to retrieve the value easily either in javascript `document.querySelector(".inputbox").getAttribute('data-holdout')` or in jquery `$(".inputbox").data("holdout")`

Comment: I will try this first mohamedrias. Can this also be used in <field> tag? because I am passing the field as an XML type before the form is generated in the front end.

Comment: DOM apis applies to both xml as well as html. So you can use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` in both. When your generating the form use `setAttribute` to define the holdout

Comment: maxlength="20"  
required="true" 
data-holdout = "'.$filter_record['holdout'].'"       
class = "datefrom"         
filter="user_utc" />

Comment: `"<input type='text' max-length='20' data-holdout='"+$filter_record['holdout']+"'>";`

Comment: unfortunately, data-holdout is undefined when the page is rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73822/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-break-the-law).